# Не могу разобраться, в чем соль?

Tags: javascript, node.js, password, password-hash

Для хеширования паролей заюзал пакет `argon2`.
Для тестов написал вот такой код

```
const argon2 = require('argon2');
const { Buffer } = require('buffer');
const pass = 'password'

const passList = ['qwerty', 'password','zzzz' ]

async function main() {
    let salt = Buffer.from('qwertyuiopasdfgh');
    const hash = await argon2.hash(pass, { salt }); // $argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$cXdlcnR5dWlvcGFzZGZnaA$bVkS9BbKvWp8zwR0G3Ft3u8qT3vcAbe7EDjJXxxyI1M

    for (const passItem of passList) {
      const result = await argon2.verify(hash, passItem) // false, true, false
}
}

main()
```

Как видно, в метод `verify`, я передаю только лишь пароль и его хэш, который может утекти. Никакой соли туда не добавляю. При переборе списка паролей, ожидаю увидеть три `false`. Но результат другой. Пароль установлен.

Код написан по мотивам доки https://github.com/ranisalt/node-argon2

Comment: так хэш делали с солью

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что соль уже в хеше. Вот она: `cXdlcnR5dWlvcGFzZGZnaA`.

```js
> Buffer.from('qwertyuiopasdfgh').toString('base64')
'cXdlcnR5dWlvcGFzZGZnaA=='
```

P.S. `Buffer` в Node.JS это глобальный объект, так что его можно не `require`-ить.

Comment: Так это понятно. Непонятно как это уберегает от взлома. Вот у злоумышленика есть словарь паролей и этот хеш (с солью) - при сопоставлении, он ведь легко подберет пароль. Или нет?

Comment: Нет. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: @Дмытрык, индивидуальная для каждого пароля соль нужна, чтобы не допустить быстрого массового перебора по [радужным таблицам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Радужная_таблица)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ну вот, на основе этой статьи и зыждится мое непонимание) Я немного видоизменил код в вопросе, чтобы было наглядней видно проблему, которая меня смущает

Comment: Соль не защищает от перебора одного пароля одного пользователя. Но если, например у вас украли базу паролей 1000 пользователей, то с солью злоумышленнику понадобиться в 1000 раз больше времени на подбор, т.к. для каждого пользователя надо будет посчитать индивидуальный хеш с его солью. И это тоже описано в вики в разделе «Преимущества использования соли в системах авторизации»